# How to passing props in React + TypeScript from parents to children component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have method in parents component:

```
private handleLoginFormChange = (name: string) =>(e: any) => {
   const newState = cloneDeep(this.state);
   const newValue = e.target.value;
   set(newState, name, newValue);
   this.setState(newState);
  }
```

I try to pass it in children component.

```
<LoginForm 
 submitLogin={this.handleLoginForm}
 onChangeForm={this.handleLoginFormChange}
 />
```

I did childten component in function style

```
interface Props {
  submitLogin?: () => void;
  onChangeForm?: (event: any) => void;
};

function LoginForm ({submitLogin, onChangeForm}:Props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="text"
             onChange={onChangeForm} 
             className="form-control mainLoginInput"
              id="login" placeholder="логин | телефон"
               />
            <input 
            type="password"
            onChange={onChangeForm}
             className="form-control mainLoginInput"
              id="password" placeholder="пароль" />
            <button onClick={submitLogin} type="button" className="btn btn-dark mainLoginButton">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I don't know how to right wright onChangeForm in interface. 
I try to do some thing like this

```
interface Props {
  submitLogin?: () => void;
  onChangeForm?: (name: string) => void;
};
```

but in this case error

```
(15,14): Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void) | undefined'.
```

Can you help me, how to pass props name and get it back.

Comment: I think the error is clear and you should change

onChangeForm?: (name: string) => void;

to 

onChangeForm?: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your event function to the component, you have to call its wrapper

```js
<LoginForm 
  submitLogin={this.handleLoginForm} 
  onChangeForm={this.handleLoginFormChange('name')} 
/>
```